# Как заменить поля about:support Firefox в selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Как заменить первые 6 полей, передающиеся в about:support под Application Basics

[image]
useragent как менять я понял

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)
profile.update_preferences()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, seleniumwire_options=options)
```

А как заменить остальные поля ?